# Get Forms Data in Square Payment

Tags: square-connect, square

I have CaptainForm plugin installed on WordPress integrated website, CaptainForm is having Square Payment Gateway integrated with it.

I have created Form using CaptainForm and having Checkout Button on it, When I click on Checkout Button, the page is taking me to below page (as shown in screen shot) . I want the Square Payment Form should automatically capture the data like Name, Address, entered on form (of CaptainForm) to its Payment Page -

[Square Payment Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bAq4.png)

Square Payment Page is only capturing the Email from CaptainForm Forms (filled on previous page)

How can i capture all the data like Name, address, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two fields that you can pre-populate are the buyer's email and the buyer's shipping address. You will not be able to pass the buyer's name to automatically fill it out. In order to have the address populate, you need to fill out the `pre_populate_shipping_address` field when calling `CreateCheckout`. I'm not familiar with the CaptainForm plugin, so I don't know how it works with the plugin.

Reference: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createcheckout